# NSApplicationDelegate prevent window if command line present

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a simple single window app, with a drop target on it for files. This works fine. However, I also want that when it is started with a command line, it just processes those files instead, rather than showing a window.

Is there a delegate method in NSApplicationDelegate that I can prevent the window from showing, process the files and quit the application in?

Comment: Clearly I could just process it in the main() pre NSApp part, but the NSApplicationDelegate actually performs the processing on the file, so I want to be able to process it there if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the window **not to show when loaded from the nib file**. There's a setting in the inspector in the Interface builder.

Then you can show the window if necessary, using methods described in [this documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

But this will still show the icon in the Dock while your app is processing the file.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think that way round. Now I have it hidden, and in appDidFinishLaunching, I check the command line arguments, if there are some I process them and quit, otherwise i makeKeyAndOrderFront on the window

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent showing the main window like Yuji said. There's also a notification called applicationDidFinishLaunching: 
There you can process your files and quit the application with [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:self];

Comment: That is where I was processing it, just the starting with the window hidden was my logical block!

Answer (score 1):

The most maintainable and simple approach I've seen to this is to put your commandline version in a separate executable as a simple Foundation program, and then make your Cocoa program just call it, handling the UI. Doing it this way gets rid of many of the things you'd need to work around. You can then install links to your commandline version where you like.

If you dislike using `NSTask` for this, then put your logic into a shared framework, and layer GUI and commandline apps on top of it.

Comment: Not sure why that is simpler or more maintainable? It works very well as the application as above, I don't need to process the command line twice as I would have to with that method, I don't need an installer to put it wherever, and I don't need additional permissions to instal another application.  In fact offhand I can't see any real advantage to it?

Comment: You don't need any of the things you describe. The additional application goes into your bundle and doesn't require an installer and is generally invisible to the user (except via a link you provide, which they would need in any case). The reason I find it more reliable is that it gets rid of all the corner cases. For instance, it doesn't flash the icon in the task bar when you're running in command-line mode. It launches faster (because it can avoid things like that, as well as reading NIBs, etc). And it separates core functionality from UI concerns.